# Select iron-ajax element on body

Tags: javascript, polymer

I try include 2 element on html file looks like :

```
<html>
  <body>
    <iron-ajax id="requestContent"></iron-ajax>
    <my-custom-element></my-custom-element>
  </body>
</html>
```

At `my-custom-element` I have a link tag with `on-click` property, I want to select `iron-ajax` element by `id` when I click a link on `my-custom-element`. How can I do that?

```
<dom-module id="my-custom-element">
  <template>
    <a href$="/target-page" on-click="_aFunction">click me</a>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymenr({
       is: 'my-custom-element',
       _aFunction: function(){
          console.log(this.parentNode); // output element body
          console.log(this.parentNode.$); // undefined
          // console.log(this.parentNode.$.requestContent);
       }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: This is probably not a good idea. This is because `my-custom-element` has to have a parent that has `iron-ajax` as a child. Really you should fire an event to the parent element which can then decide processes to execute. Have a look at the [dom-bind](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/dom-bind) template and [firing custom events](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events#custom-events)

Comment: @BenThomas fyi, if I put `iron-ajax` and `my-custom-element` to another custom element it's works. But I want to outside element which is inside body tag

Answer (score 0):

The child triggers a custom event with the id to be selected,
the parent triggers a function that selects the id.

Parent

```
 <iron-ajax id="requestContent" on-select-ajax="handleSelection"></iron-ajax>

          handleSelection: function(e) {
            // do what you have to do with e.name 
            // you can pass the data anywhere
          }
```

Child

```
<dom-module id="my-custom-element">
  <template>
    <a href$="/target-page" on-tap="_aFunction">click me</a>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymenr({
       is: 'my-custom-element',
      _aFunction: function(e, detail) {
        this.fire('select-ajax', {name: requestContent});
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

ps: I changed on-click to on-tap to allow clicks and touch on your link.